# PHP: searching for a specific element somewhere in an HTML document

Tags: php, search, dom, xpath

I have a rather large HTML document that I am trying to extract information from. I have gotten as far as figuring out that I probably need to use a DOMDocument object, and xPath. I need to return the contents of a specific DIV. The good news is that it has a class tag associated with it. The bad news is that it is buried in some non-specific location in the HTML document, within several layers of othere DIV's, and that location may change. So, what I am looking to return the contents of the div.

```
<div class='target'>Return all of this stuff</div>
```

The trick seems to be in that I don't know the particular location that this particular div will be in. I need a way to just say 'search the entire DOM for the div with the class-name of target'. there may be multiple coinsurance, but probably not. However, once I get the, probably array of element contents, I can take it from there. And again, using PHP 5.4.

Comment: You say you figured out you need DomDocument and xpath so why haven't you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xpath query you need is:

```
$query = "//div[@class='target']";
```

which you can use with a `DOMXPath` object by invoking the `query` method.

Comment: I had already tried this, and it wasn't working. However, I later found that it was due to a stupid programming error that I made. I deserve to lose the two points or reputation. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

*If* I understand correctly, this can be accomplished with native php string handling alone.

Have you tried something along the lines of.

```
$start = stripos($STRINGYOUARESEARCHING, "<div class='target'>")
$end= stripos($STRINGYOUARESEARCHING, "</div>",start);
$contents= substr($STRINGYOUARESEARCHING, $start, $end-$start)
```

Let me know if this isn't the *kind* of answer you're looking for... here I assume you have a large block of HTML with your target in it?

(Note: You may have to offset $end or $start by `strlen(<div class='target'>)`

Comment: Does not account for child divs within the target div.

Comment: Have you found a solution?  What is the content of the child divs?  Is something ambiguous?  It seems like you should be able extend this to iterate over an arbitrary number of children.... I'll post a more complete solution if you tell me more.... I spent a few hours once messing with something like this myself..

Comment: No. This is a very bad answer. The contents of the divs are text, and other HTML elements, including other divs.

Comment: I got it to work once, when I started out with PHP.  I'll have to learn about that xpath stuff... its looks much more elegant... but this works as long as the programmer makes the proper assumptions.  Gotta check out that Xpath stuff, though...